# How to style embedded plotly plots as pseudo-sparklines?

Tags: r, plotly, reactable

The `reactable` packages supports embedded htmlwidgets.  I can include plotly plots inside the cells, but I haven't been able to size them appropriately.  I'd like for them to be very compact and fine-pointed like sparklines.

`plot_ly(..., height = 50, width = 300)` successfully shrinks the height of the figure, but the line strokes are heavy and the axis titles take up a lot of space.  If I can make the figure more fine-pointed and completely remove the axis labels, maybe I could get there.

`layout(xaxis = list(label = NULL))` does not remove the labels and I don't know how to read the documentation for the layout options. https://plotly.com/r/reference/#Layout_and_layout_style_objects

Any ideas are appreciated!

```
library(tidyverse)
library(reactable)
library(plotly)

dat <- mtcars |> 
  select(where(is.numeric)) |> 
  pivot_longer(everything()) |> 
  group_by(name) |> 
  summarize(plt = list(value))

my_plot <- function(value, ...) {
  tibble(value) |>
    plot_ly(type = "violin", x = ~value, width = 300, height = 50) |> 
    layout(autosize = TRUE, xaxis = list(label = NULL))
}

dat |> 
  reactable(
    columns = list(
      plt = colDef(cell = my_plot)
    )
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some minor issues with your code:

1. set `~value` to y
2. if you want sparkling lines then use `type= 'scatter'` and `mode = 'lines'`
3. Modify layout as you like

Tweak your code like this:

```
my_plot <- function(value, ...) {
  tibble(value) |>
    plot_ly(type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', y = ~value, width = 300, height = 50) |> 
    layout(xaxis = list(showticklabels = FALSE, ticks = ''),
           margin = list(l = 1, r = 0, t = 0, b = 0))
}
```

[image]